# How to make GoogleCL work? Can't configure the OAuth Token

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-client, googlecl

I just installed GoogleCL but can't make it work. When I enter the command it requests me a username and then the following message is shown:

[image]

Could someone show me how to get this OAuth token and what to do with it?

What I could do until now was to download a JSON file from the API Console but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: googlecl is not supported by google anymore. They simply didn't add oauth2 support to googlecl and dropped support for oauth1 everywhere. If you ever come across something that could replace googlecl please share that info.

Comment: @Krystian Thanks for your reply. I found a solution at https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive and it worked like a charm. Let me know if I can help with anything.